# Digital Ocean or upgrade physical computers?

Tags: digital-ocean

Not sure where to post this question, but I was looking at DO and it seemed pretty compelling.

My coworker and I need new computers pretty soon at the office just to improve quality of life for when we do analysis or wrangling data on large files/queries.

I could purchase two physical computers which will become outdated (the options we have already look fairly old actually, we are stuck with Dell), or perhaps we can 'move to the cloud'. The upfront cost would be several thousand dollars and we would wait for a few months before receiving them if we chose the physical machines.

A challenge we have had is sharing tasks (like a script that cleans data and loads it into the database) and sharing the raw data files (prior to adding to the database). It would be nice to centralize all of this stuff because there has been a growing fragmentation and it makes it challenging to travel for long periods of time in case something breaks.

Is it possible to centralize some files and scripts on a DO instance and then both of us can access that machine and add new scripts, pull data, or make alterations as needed? Our computers at the office would just be for email and stuff, all of the heavy lifting could be done with DO.